# Javascript / Jquery extract whole CLASS descriptor from a partial selection descriptor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript / Jquery function that controls groups of checkboxes.

The checkboxes are created on PHP form from a database call so I am iteratively going through a recordset and creating checkboxes in html.

For each checkbox I assign it a class of "checkboxgroup" + a numeric identifier to create a group of 'like' records.
I end up with multiple checkboxes like this:

```
    <tr class="tablebody">
        <td><input name="contactresolveid2048" id="contactresolveid2048" type="checkbox" class="checkboxgroup0"/></td>
        <td>David&nbsp;Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablebody">
        <td><input name="contactresolveid19145" id="contactresolveid19145" type="checkbox" class="checkboxgroup0"/></td>
        <td>graham&nbsp;Foots</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablebody">
        <td><input name="contactresolveid19146" id="contactresolveid19146" type="checkbox" class="checkboxgroup0"/></td>
        <td>Tom&nbsp;Silly</td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see, these 3 checkboxes have a class of 'checkboxgroup0'

The following function detects a click on ANY of the checkbox groups on a form (of which there may be many) and unchecks any checkboxes (belonging to the same group) that are not the clicked one.

```
    $('[class^="checkboxgroup"]').click(function() {
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var $checkboxgroup = $('input.'+thisClass);
        $checkboxgroup.filter(':checked').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```

Under most circumstances this works fine when the only class is 'checkboxgroup0'.

However when validation takes place JQuery validate appends a 'valid' or 'error' class to the class list of any fields that pass or fail validation, so I can endup having an .attr(class) of 'checkboxgroup0 valid'.

My question is this:

How do I return the whole class name of the partially selected class WITHOUT any extraneous classes?

By using the selector $('[class^="checkboxgroup"]') I need  the whole part of that selector 'checkboxgroup0' and no other classes that may be assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue you've encountered is one of the reasons why using incremental id/class attributes are not good practice.

To work around this issue with your JS you can instead use the same class on *every* checkbox. You can then group them by a `data` attribute instead. Using this method means that the number of classes on an element or their position within the `class` attribute string does not matter.

Try this example:

```js
$('.checkboxgroup').click(function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  let $group = $(`.checkboxgroup[data-group="${$this.data('group')}"]`);
  $group.not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="tablebody">
    <td><input name="contactresolveid2048" id="contactresolveid2048" type="checkbox" class="checkboxgroup" data-group="0" /></td>
    <td><label for="contactresolveid2048">David Smith</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablebody">
    <td><input name="contactresolveid19145" id="contactresolveid19145" type="checkbox" class="checkboxgroup" data-group="0" /></td>
    <td><label for="contactresolveid19145">graham Foots</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablebody">
    <td><input name="contactresolveid19146" id="contactresolveid19146" type="checkbox" class="checkboxgroup" data-group="0" /></td>
    <td><label for="contactresolveid19146">Tom Silly</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***However***, it's worth noting that what you're attempting to do can be far better achieved using HTML alone. Simply use a `radio` input and give them all the same `name` attribute, then you get the behaviour you're trying to create for free:

```html
<table>
  <tr class="tablebody">
    <td><input name="contactresolve" id="contactresolveid2048" type="radio" /></td>
    <td><label for="contactresolveid2048">David Smith</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablebody">
    <td><input name="contactresolve" id="contactresolveid19145" type="radio" /></td>
    <td><label for="contactresolveid19145">graham Foots</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablebody">
    <td><input name="contactresolve" id="contactresolveid19146" type="radio" /></td>
    <td><label for="contactresolveid19146">Tom Silly</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am way ahead of you with the idea of a radio group instead, however as ever this example is the most simplistic example of a much more complicated set of issues that prevent the use of radio groups for skinning this particular cat.


The 'data-' attribute solution, however, is a much cleaner way forward. I guess any custom attribute would also have done the trick thinking about it. I had forgotten about custom attribute (haven't used them for years).